# Powershell, Task Scheduler or loop and sleep

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-task-scheduler

I have a job that needs to go off every minute or so,

it loads a DLL i have written in C# that retrieves state for an SQL Server Mirror (Primary, Mirror and witness) for a number of databases;

it allows us to poke DNS to show where the primary instances are. Please don't mention Clustering - We're not doing that.

I can't be arsed to write a service, there simply isn't enough time

do I

- Task Scheduler - every minute: Invoke a powershell script that loads the DLL does the business
- Task scheduler - At Startup : Invoke a similer powershell script that loads the DLL once but then loops and sleeps, refreshing the Object that the DLL exposes.

Pros and cons?

Comment: If you can't be 'arsed' then why should we be 'arsed' to help?

Comment: Timescales, It could and should be done but I've never written a C# service and the deadline approaches like the grim reaper.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Powershell is a heavy thing to load every minute for a small task. You can create mass swap in this way. From this point of view the second approach looks a little bit better. But in the second case monitoring this job if it is running or not will be your problem.

So, if you have enough cache memory to fit powershell with its dependencies - try the first option. If not - stick with the second. And think of writing service anyway :)

Comment: I shall write the service - but not this week. Thanks!